# How to know which of the resize handles is used.?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-resizable

Before resizing (on the start event), need to know which of the resize handles is used. How to know it?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, it's difficult to know the context of the question, but the key is to look for a defining attribute of the element in question.

For example:

- Look at the ID of the handle that is used. `$('.handle').attr('id');`
- Look for any defining attributes in the classnames. `$('.handle').attr('class');`.

For the second option, you could then `split()` on the classnames to examine what other values are available.